# How to: CRUD Using AngularJS and MVC Web API

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, crud

I would like to use AngularJS and MVC Web API to create a form and its CRUD operations (see image below)

The form is constituted of three tables: Page, Preamble, Sections. It also has 3 drop down lists that will need to be populated from the database.

This is my first attempt to create a project like this one, and I am finding lots of examples and most of them use only one table.

Do anybody has an tutorial/ example in which more than one table is used?

[image]

Comment: structure of form layout has little relevance to the model you use for the data. Question is far too broad. You need to narrow your issues down to more specifics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are *lots* of Angular tutorials at the end of a Google search, but can I suggest that you not think of your page controls/layout as being sourced from tables in a database but more as results returned from an API call (actually you shouldn't even be thinking about it like that, but it will start you on the right road) - ultimately these values may well be formed as a result of some database query but from the UI perspective that's implementation detail that it shouldn't be privy to.

Rather than:

```
Title, SEO Title, Percent Page = "Page Table"
```

Consider:

```
Title, SEO Title, Percent Page = api/pages/{page}
```

Then the implementation behind `api/pages/{page}` is hidden from the UI and so not tightly coupled to the database schema.

Comment: Thank you Scott Perham. This has offered clarity.